# How to implement observer design pattern for UIStepper

Tags: swift, observer-pattern, uistepper

So say I have a VC with a counter (Int) value with UIStepper.
The view also has 2 subviews which display the counter value in different ways. These are custom sub-views.

1. One subview will say 'My value is 3'
2. The second subview will say Counter: '23'
   So the main vc will have an observer which will kick in when user taps on Increment or Decrement on UIStepper.
   When value of counter changes, the observer broadcasts the updated value to whoever is listening and the 2 subviews are updated accordingly.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd perfer a Target-Action to an Observer, as it is far easier to trace/debug.  Have the action be a method that updates the two views.

A simple example where the two views both provide an 'update(for value: Int)` method

```
// as part of some set up method
stepper.addTarget(self, action: #(selectorUpdated(_:)), for: .valueChanged)


@objc func selectorUpdated(_ stepper: UIStepper) {
  view1.update(for: stepper.value)
  view2.update(for: stepper.value)
}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this using observing design pattern using protocol

Comment: You could use an observer,  but it's a legacy ObjC pattern more than a Swift pattern and not recommended when there are more "swifty" alternatives.

Comment: what are the swift alternatives?

Comment: Target-Action as above is the most obvious.  It's standard UIKIt, built into UIControl so that it is made available to all the UIKit controls (they subclass UIControl for this reason).